# Adding link to a image breaks everything else

Tags: html, css

So this is a simple line of images, with hover effects, I have it doing everything I need, except when I add a link to open up a new page 
[image]
 so do i need to remake everything and use a different approach or is there a way to somehow fix the issue? Thanks :)

UPDATE!

The code might not be perfect, but I added

.box-1 a {
display:contents:
}

and that solved everything !

```css
.container-1 {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.box-1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.box-1:hover img {
  filter: blur(3px) brightness(85%);
}

.box-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.box-1 :not(img) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.box-1 h2 {
  top: 50%;
}

.box-1:hover :not(img) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <a href="c1.html" target="_blank">
      <img class="candle-image" src="image/candlesp/IMG_0900.jpg"/></a>
    <h2>Festivity</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="image/candlesp/IMG_0903.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>Cinnamon</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="image/candlesp/IMG_0917.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>Forest</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the `<img>` tag does not need and does not use a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accidentally making `<a>` `position: absolute`. Instead of using `:not`, why not target the `h2` directly `.box-1 h2` and also try giving it a width and height

Answer (score 0):

You close img tag in anchor tag

```
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <a href="c1.html" target="_blank">
      <img class="candle-image" src="image/candlesp/IMG_0900.jpg"></a>
    <h2>Festivity</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="image/candlesp/IMG_0903.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>Cinnamon</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="image/candlesp/IMG_0917.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>Forest</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```